# Calculating download speed in libcurl?

Tags: c++, networking, libcurl

So I've been using libcurl to have a little go with HTTP requests like GET, and I have managed to create the progress function callback to see how much has downloaded. However, what I don't know is the formula in order to calculate download speed as you go (similar to how browsers show you the download speed, eg Chrome).

I originally thought of using this:

```
downloadSpeed = amountCurrentlyDownloaded / secondsSinceDownloadStarted
```

Similar to the

```
speed = distance / time
```

formula. However, this isn't accurate. For example, if the download hasn't changed at all, `downloadSpeed` will go down slightly, but not down to zero.

So what is the correct formula to calculate download speed?

Comment: There is no 'correct' formula. It is always a description of a variable process, and how you believe that process should be described by a single number. What you might find more attractive is to use overlapping windows: calculate how much was downloaded in blocks of, say, one second, and then average the last couple of blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Think of a car.  Do you want to know the average speed for the trip, or do you want to know your current speed?  Your formula gives average speed.

Since you are receiving data in increments, you can't just do like a spedometer and see a current speed.  Instead, maybe you could update every few seconds, and when you do, divide the number of chars since the 
Last update by the time since the last update (need to use higher precision timer than seconds).

Perhaps you want to display both the current and average speeds.  That's just a question of what will "feel" best to your users.